# Excel: How to split a column into two columns based off a third, odd/even parameter column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I will be referencing the below picture:
[image]

I seek to split up the FirstValue Column into the two columns right of it; however, I want to split the columns based off the Parameter column. When the Parameter value is odd, I want to copy the values only to the OtherValue1 column. When the Parameter value is even, I want to copy the values only to the OtherValue2 column. After reading forums and trying excel's "Text to Columns" feature, I am unable to find a solution.

Is there a way implement this using VBA?

*Note: The worksheet is actually about 10,000 rows long, so speed would also be helpful.

**EDIT**:
Here is the code I have so far. I am getting Object errors in this line of code: `.Cells(2, MF1Col).Formula = "=IF(MOD(paraformula,2)=1,WTRfor,"")"`

```
    Dim rw As Worksheet
Dim secondCell, MF1Cell, MF2Cell, paraCell, MF1formula, MF2formula, paraformula, WTRfor As Range
Dim secondCol As Long, MF1Col As Long, MF2Col As Long, paraCol As Long
 Set rw = ActiveSheet

With rw

    Set secondCell = .Rows(1).Find("FirstValue”)

    ' Check if the column with “FirstValue” is found

    'Insert Two Columns after FirstValue
    If Not secondCell Is Nothing Then
        secondCol = secondCell.Column
        .Columns(secondCol + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Columns(secondCol + 2).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Cells(1, secondCol + 1).Value = "OtherValue1"
        .Cells(1, secondCol + 2).Value = "OtherValue2"
        .Activate

    Set MF1Cell = .Rows(1).Find("OtherValue1")
    MF1Col = MF1Cell.Column
    Set MF2Cell = .Rows(1).Find("OtherValue2")
    MF2Col = MF2Cell.Column
    Set paraCell = .Rows(1).Find("Parameter")
    paraCol = paraCell.Column

    Set paraformula = Range(.Cells(2, paraCol).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
    Set MF1formula = Range(.Cells(2, MF1Col).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
    Set WTRfor = Range(.Cells(2, secondCol).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
    .Cells(2, MF1Col).Formula = "=IF(MOD(" & paraformula & ",2)=1," & WTRfor & ","""")"
    Range(.Cells(2, MF1Col).Address).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Set MF2formula = Range(.Cells(2, MF2Col).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
    .Cells(2, MF2Col).Formula = "=IF(MOD(" & paraformula & ",2)=0," & WTRfor & ","""")"
    Range(.Cells(2, MF2Col).Address).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste   

End If
End With
```

Comment: In the parameter column there will never be a decimal point. There are only integers

Comment: to get double quotes in VBA, you need 4 of them, so `,"")` would become `,"""")`

Comment: @SeanCheshire, Now, all that appears in the OtherValue column is #NAME? "The formula contains unrecognized text" It is just putting in the exact text, and not referencing the addresses

Comment: `"=IF(MOD(" & paraformula & ",2)=1," & WTRfor & ","""")"`

Comment: @SeanCheshire Thanks! That worked great for the second row, but when copying down to apply it for the rest of the 10,000 rows, it just kept the same values. I am assuming this is because the " $ $ " just got the values into the formula instead of the actual cell address, so when applied to the rest of the rows, it didn't work

Comment: the $ are from the `.Address` being absolute. change to: `.Address(RowAbsolute:=False,ColumnAbsolute:=False)`, and the $ signs will vanish *(alternatively, edit the formula to remove the $ signs before copying it)*

Comment: @SeanCheshire Sorry for the misinformation. The formula is not containing $s but rather just numbers. The cell looks like this after I run the macro: `IF(MOD(3,2)=1, 4, "")` and then it displays 4 in the cell. It is putting literals in formula instead of references; however, I changed all the .Address places to include the code about absolutes being false just in case. Still no effect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13625/discussion-between-sean-cheshire-and-jonny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in C2, `=IF(MOD(E2,2)=1,B2,"")`
in D2, `=IF(MOD(E2,2)=0,B2,"")`

copy these down to the end of your data

assuming the same format (Data,Col1,Col2,Parameter), but using relative addressing
Column 1: `=IF(MOD(OFFSET(C2,0,2),2)=1,OFFSET(C2,0,-1),"")` *replace C2 with the current cell*
Column 2: `=IF(MOD(OFFSET(D2,0,1),2)=0,OFFSET(D2,0,-2),"")` *replace D2 with the current cell*

again, copy and paste - once you have the first one correct, excel will adjust the formula for the current cell

Comment: What if the column rows that they are in are not consistent. Could it be updated to search by column header, instead of cell fields (ie. not E2,B2)?

Comment: Could it be expanded to not indlude C2, or D2 at all? Something like this `Rows(1).Find("OtherValue1")` and `.Cells(1, columnVariable + 2).Value`

Comment: it could, but that would add a great deal of complexity, and use volatile functions, which results in the formula or code being re-evaluated every time the spreadsheet changes, not just when you enter the formula. I will have to do that coding at home (unless someone can come up with something in the meantime)

Comment: Additionally, the Parameter column is also not consistant, so I'm not entirely sure an OFFSET would work.

Comment: I have updated my code with the attempt to search by column header. I am getting error messages listed above. Can you see a problem with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

For Cell D2:

```
    =IF(MOD(E2,2),B2,"")
```

Explanation:
If Range E2 is not divisible by two, the display value from B2, otherwise display nothing.

you can reverse this by inserting a 'NOT' around the MOD for Cell C2:

```
    =IF(NOT(MOD(E2,2)),B2,"")
```

Comment: swap the formulas around - Column C is for odd, column D is for even

Answer (score 0):

VBA:

```
Sub odd_even()

a = 1                                                           ' start row
b = 10                                                          ' end row
c = 1                                                           ' column with values inputs

For d = a To b                                                  ' FOR loop from start row to end row

    If ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c) Mod 2 Then                       'mod becomes high when value is odd
        ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c + 2) = ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c)   'odd value gets copied to the odd-column   ( two to the right of the values)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c + 3) = ""                        'same row on even-column gets cleared
    Else:
        ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c + 3) = ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c)   'even value gets copied to the even-column ( three to the right of the values)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c + 2) = ""                        'same row on odd-column gets cleared
    End If

Next d                                                          ' go to next row

End Sub
```

Comment: this question was asked three months ago, and is already answered if you have read the comments.